# how to get style sheets for the Bootstrap sample templates

Tags: javascript

I am brand new to bootstrap and trying to get ready for school.
I like the Carousel template, how do I get the style sheet for it on getbootstrap.com? I right-clicked on it and copy the source code but I need a style sheet to link it to. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about this example : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

This example assumes that you've been through bootstrap getting started guide : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ where you will find the css to include or download

Answer (score 0):

you could use CDN in your template file.

just include below code inside `<head></head>` tag of your template file

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```